# How to know if process died

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I want to determine if some process/app is crashed and if so, run another application (made on automator that restarts all running apps).

How can I check if some specific process is still running? Maybe i can use the app ID, but first i need to have access to the application status.

Comment: Can't you use `ps -e | grep something`?

Comment: yes, but it only gives me the app ID and all that information, i need to know if it is crashed/"not responding"

Answer (score 0):

If you forked it yourself, you can have the parent monitor it. Otherwise, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2050/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003081-CH1-SECTION8).